# Prove the universal property of free abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove the following: Given a set $S$ show that the free abelian group (free group quotient the commutator) generated by $S$ is the smallest abelian group that contains $S$.

The thing is that I was thinking to do it by contradiction, but once I consider that there is a smaller abelian group such that it contains $S$ I don't know how to proceed. My other question is; Is the universal property of free abelian groups? or is the one here

http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/jonpak/N9.pdf

( page 7)

Thanks a lot for your help. **In fact, Can you help me to prove the first question please :)**

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have a set map $f:S \rightarrow A$, where $A$ is an abelian group. You have to show that it factors uniquely through the free abelian group on $S$.

I wouldn't advise to prove this by contradiction. Just use the universal property of the free group on $S$, and then use the universal property of the abelianization of a group.

Comment: So, is it the result seen in the link I posted?